# convert react function to typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm quite new to typescript and I was hoping someone could help me convert my react function to typescript. It's a sort array that should take in a string a value as param and sort my data by that value.

Currently the errors I'm getting an `Parameter type is implicity any` on the `type` param and the same error on `const sortProperty = types[type]`. Not sure how to typescript-tify so would appreciate the help.

The function in question:

```
 const sortArray = (type) => {
  const types = {
    state: 'state',
    brewery_type: 'brewery_type',
  };
  const sortProperty = types[type];
  const sorted = [...response].sort((a, b) => b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty]);
  setResponse(sorted);
};

sortArray(sortType)
```

The rest of the page:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import beer from './beerMug.png';
import useFetch from './api/useFetch';
import axios from 'axios';

type ResponseType = {
  response: Object[] | Object, 
  error: string
}

type Breweries = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  brewery_type: string;
  state: string;
} 

type SortTypes = {
  state: string;
  brewery_type: string;
}

function App() {

  const [response, setResponse] = useState<any>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);
  const [sortType, setSortType] = useState("name");
  // const { response, error }: { response: object, error: string} = useFetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries");


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
     try {
       const res = await axios.get("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries");
       setResponse(res.data);
       } catch (error) {
       setError(error);
     }
   }

   fetchData();
 }, []);

 const sortArray = (type: string) => {
  const types = {
    state: 'state',
    brewery_type: 'brewery_type',
  };
  const sortProperty: SortTypes = types[type];
  const sorted = [...response].sort((a, b) => b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty]);
  setResponse(sorted);
};

sortArray(sortType);

  console.log(response);

  const mapper = () => {
    if(response instanceof Array){
        return (
          <>
          {response.map((item: Breweries) => (
              <div className="item" key={item.id}>
                <ul>
                <li>{item.name}</li>
                <li>{item.state}</li>
                <li>{item.brewery_type}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            ))}
          </>
        )
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
          <img src={beer} className="image" />
          <h1>Sherman Brewery</h1>
          <img src={beer} className="image" />
        </div>
        <div className="container">
        <div className="selectContainer">
          <select name="brewer" id="brewer" onChange={(e) => setSortType(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="" defaultValue="Sort By:" disabled hidden>Sort By:</option>
            <option value="1">State</option>
            <option value="2">Type</option>
          </select>
        </div>
            {mapper()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
``
```

Comment: Typescript functions require type annotations for their arguments (in most situations). If you want to use TypeScript, you must add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of things that are not quite right here.  For one, it's pointless to lookup a value in an object when the keys and the values are the same! `types[type]` is just `type`.

```
const types = {
  state: 'state',
  brewery_type: 'brewery_type',
};
const sortProperty: SortTypes = types[type];
```

We need to ensure the following things:

- Our `sortProperty` is a valid key of the brewery objects in the `response` array.
- The `type` variable passed to the `sortArray` function is one of these valid keys.
- The `sortType` `useState` hook only allows these valid keys.
- The `response` `useState` hook only allows brewery objects.

You already defined a type `Breweries` so we can use that in a bunch of places.  I am going to call it `Brewery` instead since it describes a single brewery object.  You can delete the `SortTypes` type as we can use `keyof Brewery` to get the valid keys.

So now here are all of the places where you need types:

---

```
const [response, setResponse] = useState<Brewery[]>([]);
```

Our `response` can only be an array of `Brewery` objects.  The empty array that we start with is fine.

---

```
const [sortType, setSortType] = useState<keyof Brewery>("name");
```

Our `sortType` can only be a key of `Brewery`.  It is a subset of `string` that only allows these four literal strings.

---

```
const res = await axios.get<Brewery[]>("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries");
```

We can tell our `axios` call what type of response to expect.  By default it will be `any` so you won't get an error if you don't.

---

```
const sortArray = (sortProperty: keyof Brewery) => {
```

We can only call `sortArray` with a property name of a `Brewery`.

---

```
const sortArray = (sortProperty: keyof Brewery) => {
  const sorted = [...response].sort((a, b) =>
    sortProperty === "id" ?
      b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty] :
      a[sortProperty].localeCompare(b[sortProperty])
  );
  setResponse(sorted);
};
```

We have to fix up the implementation a bit because Typescript doesn't allow you to subtract strings.  Our values could be a `number` (if `sortProperty` is `id`) or a `string` so this is a little annoying.  There might be a cleaner way.

---

```
onChange={(e) => setSortType(e.target.value as keyof Brewery)}
```

The value of the `select` is just a `string` so we have to assert that it is actually a key of `Brewery` in order to set it as the sort type.  When we use `as` to make an assertion we are telling Typescript to trust us, so we need to make sure that we are right.

---

```
<option value="name" defaultValue="Sort By:" disabled hidden>Sort By:</option>
<option value="state">State</option>
<option value="brewery_type">Type</option>
```

The `value` property of all of your `option` elements should be a key of `Brewery` or else our assertion is wrong.

---

There are some other React errors.  I am getting the "Too many re-renders" error due to `sortArray` updating the `response` on every render.  So instead of updating the state, let's just return the sorted array.  Then we can call the function before we `map` the `response`.

Complete Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

// just a placeholder for your actual image
const beer =
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Beer3.svg/1024px-Beer3.svg.png";

type Brewery = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  brewery_type: string;
  state: string;
};

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<Brewery[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);
  const [sortType, setSortType] = useState<keyof Brewery>("name");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get<Brewery[]>(
          "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries"
        );
        if (res! instanceof Array) {
          throw new Error("response is not an array");
        }
        setResponse(res.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const sortArray = (sortProperty: keyof Brewery) => {
    return [...response].sort((a, b) =>
      sortProperty === "id"
        ? b[sortProperty] - a[sortProperty]
        : a[sortProperty].localeCompare(b[sortProperty])
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <div className="header">
          <img src={beer} className="image" alt="Beer" />
          <h1>Sherman Brewery</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="selectContainer">
            <select
              name="brewer"
              id="brewer"
              onChange={(e) => setSortType(e.target.value as keyof Brewery)}
            >
              <option value="name" defaultValue="Sort By:" disabled hidden>
                Sort By:
              </option>
              <option value="state">State</option>
              <option value="brewery_type">Type</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          {sortArray(sortType).map((
            item // don't need to state that type is Brewery because it is already known
          ) => (
            <div className="item" key={item.id}>
              <ul>
                <li>{item.name}</li>
                <li>{item.state}</li>
                <li>{item.brewery_type}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/convert-sort-function-to-typescript-1jg3w?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!